# how to search for a variable using a string? / can you search a class for a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, class, for-loop

I am taking the name of a team from a file and I need a way to find a variable of the same name, all the team name variables are under a class called team, is there a way to search for the variable. I don't know if it would be easier to do with a dictionary or not. Python

```
class team()...

Burnley = team("Burnley",[1, 0, 0, 1], True)
Southampton = team("Southampton", [1,2,1,0,0,0,1], True)
Swansea = team("Swansea",[1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],True)

df = pd.read_csv("2016-17 testing.csv")
df =df[["Date","HomeTeam","AwayTeam","FTHG","FTAG","FTR"]]

for game in df.iterrows():

    home_team = df["HomeTeam"]
    away_team = df["AwayTeam"]
```

It is here where I need to search for the home team and find the variable. The for loop is used because we'll be going down a list of results and putting that data to some use.
Thanks

Comment: Using a dictionary will help you solve the problem. Another possible way is just to make a list of all the teams. Then, you can search in this list for a team with a name equal to whatever needed.

Comment: Also, it is a good practice to start your class name with a capital letter. So, it should be named `Team`.

Comment: @MoosaSaadat The list sounds like a good idea, how would I search the list for the home team name? Can you make lists of variables?? And I will change that thanks

Comment: I am assuming your `team` class has a `name` attribute which stores the name of the team: `team("Burnley",[1, 0, 0, 1], True)`. Like here, you are passing `"Burnley"` which is the team name. So, once, you have created a list of teams, you can check if the `team.name` matches the name. For example,
`teams = [team("Burnley",[1, 0, 0, 1], True), team("Southampton", [1,2,1,0,0,0,1], True)]`
`for t in teams:`
`if t.name == "Burnley":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to use dictionaries.

```
teams = {
    'Burnley': team("Burnley",[1, 0, 0, 1], True),
    'Southampton': team("Southampton", [1,2,1,0,0,0,1], True),
    'Swansea': team("Swansea",[1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3], True)
}

# and then simply fetch values from it
Burnley = teams['Burnley']

...
for idx, game in df.iterrows():
    home_team_name = game["HomeTeam"]  # Burnley let's assume
    home_team = teams[home_team_name] 
    ...
```

---

BUT, if you really want what the question asks for, keep reading.

Let's say I have a file, `sample.py`

```
# sample.py
from pprint import pprint

variable = 'some value'
x = 20

pprint(globals())
```

Output:

```
$ python3 sample.py 
{'__annotations__': {},
 '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 '__cached__': None,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__file__': 'sample.py',
 '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fccad01eb80>,
 '__name__': '__main__',
 '__package__': None,
 '__spec__': None,
 'pprint': <function pprint at 0x7fccacefdf70>,
 'variable': 'some value',
 'x': 20}
```

As you can see, all variables defined will be added to `globals()` and it's a `dict`, which means you can get the values from it.

Therefore you can do something like this

```
# sample.py
variable = 'some value'
x = 20

variable_name = 'variable'
number_name = 'x'

value_of_variable = globals().get(variable_name)
print(f'Value of variable = {value_of_variable}')

value_of_x = globals().get(number_name)
print(f'Value of x = {value_of_x}')
```

Output:

```
Value of variable = some value
Value of x = 20
```

---

So for your case,

```
...

for idx, game in df.iterrows():
    home_team_name = game["HomeTeam"]  # Burnley let's assume
    home_team = globals().get(home_team_name)  # would give you the value of the variable `Burnley` if it exists
    ...
```

If you've read the entire answer up to here, as a suggestion I'd like to add that class names should begin with a capital letter. `class Team:` instead of `class team:`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but when I tried to use it I got a ('Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed) error I have no idea why

Comment: What it seems like, is that, you tried to use a Series object as a dictionary key. Can you show the line where the error occurred?

Comment: home_team = globals().get(home_team)

Comment: Change `df["HomeTeam"]` to `game["HomeTeam"]`. That's what I did in the answer. `df["HomeTeam"]` will give a `pd.Series` object which isn't what you want as per what I understand.

Comment: I received another error,TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str, The code is: for game in df.iterrows():
    home_team_name = game["HomeTeam"]
    home_team = globals().get(home_team_name) and the error is on line 2
    print(home_team)

Comment: @Prince_persia22 I've updated my answer. Sorry for the error. It should be `for index, game in df.iterrows(): ...`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476974/4502878) answer to see how to iterate over a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks alot I have it up and running now ;)